# Check if all rows are equal by group ID and return boolean value

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, uniqueidentifier, boolean-expression

I have a data frame where a unique ID is given to each unique instance where there is a string in either `title.1` or `title.2`. Each ID is coded with one or more names. See below:

| title.1 | title.2 | name | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | fruit | 1 |
| A | A1 | fruit | 1 |
|  | B1 | fruit | 2 |
| B |  | fruit, vegetable | 3 |
| C | C1 | vegetable, poultry, grain | 4 |
| C | C1 | vegetable, poultry | 4 |
| C | C1 | vegetable, poultry | 4 |
|  | D1 | poultry | 5 |
|  | D1 | vegetable | 5 |

I need to identify which IDs have the same name across rows and which do not. To do this, I'd like to group by ID and test to see if all `name` values are the same across all rows with that ID. Then, I'd like to append a new column with a boolean value indicating which IDs meet this condition and which do not. The output should look like this:

| title.1 | title.2 | name | ID | names.equal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | fruit | 1 | TRUE |
| A | A1 | fruit | 1 | TRUE |
|  | B1 | fruit | 2 | TRUE |
| B |  | fruit, vegetable | 3 | TRUE |
| C | C1 | vegetable, poultry, grain | 4 | FALSE |
| C | C1 | vegetable, poultry | 4 | FALSE |
| C | C1 | vegetable, poultry | 4 | FALSE |
|  | D1 | poultry | 5 | FALSE |
|  | D1 | vegetable | 5 | FALSE |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `n_distinct` on name to get the unique count and create logical with the count after grouping by ID

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(names.equal = n_distinct(name) == 1) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 5
  title.1 title.2 name                         ID names.equal
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>                     <int> <lgl>      
1 A       A1      fruit                         1 TRUE       
2 A       A1      fruit                         1 TRUE       
3 <NA>    B1      fruit                         2 TRUE       
4 B       <NA>    fruit, vegetable              3 TRUE       
5 C       C1      vegetable, poultry, grain     4 FALSE      
6 C       C1      vegetable, poultry            4 FALSE      
7 C       C1      vegetable, poultry            4 FALSE      
8 <NA>    D1      poultry                       5 FALSE      
9 <NA>    D1      vegetable                     5 FALSE
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(title.1 = c("A", "A", NA, "B", "C", "C", "C", 
NA, NA), title.2 = c("A1", "A1", "B1", NA, "C1", "C1", "C1", 
"D1", "D1"), name = c("fruit", "fruit", "fruit", "fruit, vegetable", 
"vegetable, poultry, grain", "vegetable, poultry", "vegetable, poultry", 
"poultry", "vegetable"), ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```